# python dict ends empty after iteration

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have problem using dict in python, I just end up with empty dictionary.

looks like I erase the data each itartion

this code suppose to generate a tests that include tests for each site.

thanks in advance

```
tests={}
for t in Test.objects.all():
    for s in Site.objects.all():
        site={}
        for sv in s.siteversions.all():
            siteversion=sv.version
            results=sv.results.filter(idTest=t)
            result=""
            if(results):
                result=results[0].result_test()
            site.update({sv.version:result})
        tests.update({t.name:site.copy()})
print tests

{u'load stuff': {u'X2': 'Success', u'X1': ''}}
{u'load stuff': {u'XP': 'Error'}}
{u'load stuff': {}}
{u'load stuff': {}, u'unload': {u'X2': 'Fail', u'X1': 'Error'}}
{u'load stuff': {}, u'unload': {u'XP': 'Success'}}
{u'load stuff': {}, u'unload': {}}
```

x2 and xp are versions

Comment: Seems like there should be an easier way of doing this. Looks like you have `Test`,`Site`,`SiteVersion` and `Results`. Couldn't you iterate the "results" and collect the test name, site name and site version using `select_related`?

Comment: well i need that structure for making of a table, but I do like select_related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tests.update({t.name:site.copy()})` is executed for each site but with the same key: testname and somtimes you have sites witout test -> end up with empty dictionary.

to fix this you need a strcture like the following:

```
Test1 -> site1 -> test_results1
         site2 -> test_results2
         ...

Test2 -> site1 -> test_results1
         site2 -> test_results2
         ...
```

something like this:

```
tests={}
for t in Test.objects.all():
    sites={}
    for s in Site.objects.all():
        site_results={}
        for sv in s.siteversions.all():
            results=sv.results.filter(idTest=t)
            result = ''
            if(results):
                result=results[0].result_test()
            site_results[sv.version] = result
    sites[s.name] = site_results
tests[t.name] = sites

print tests
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you have `Test` and `Site` objects, that the `Site` objects have `version`s, and that each `siteversion`'s  has a value for its `version` property and that they are all distinct? Try putting in some print statements to debug.

Also, this sort of thing:

```
site.update({sv.version:result})
```

is unnecessarily clumsy. It should be:

```
site[sv.version] = result
```

(and the same with `tests`).

Comment: it gets data, but each itertion removes the previous in the 'dict'

Answer (score 1):

> well i need that structure for making of a table, but I do like select_related

I don't think that is true.

I'm assuming that your models.py is something like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Site(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class SiteVersion(models.Model):
  name    = models.CharField()
  site    = models.ForeignKey(Site)
  results = models.ManyToManyField(Test,through='TestResults')
  class Meta:
    unique_together = ((name,site),)

class TestResults(models.Model):
  siteversion = models.ForeignKey(SiteVersion)
  test        = models.ForeignKey(Test)
  class Meta:
    unique_together = ((siteversion,test),)
  def result_test(self):
    # Not sure about this bit, presuming you've got something else on your Test model
    return self.test.XXXX(self.siteversion)
```

In which case, you should be able to do something like this:

```
table = {}
for r in TestResults.objects.select_related('test__name','siteversion__name','siteversion__site__name'):
  table.setdefault(r.test__name,{}).setdefault(r.siteversion__site__name,{})[r.siteversion__name] = r.result_test()
```